# How i can replace string in java for rewrite the sequence

Tags: java, string

Hi I am trying to do some practice in java, I found some difficulties on it. My code:

import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public class MyPracticeString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dnaSequence;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input a Sequence of DNA: ");
        String dnaInput=in.nextLine();

        if (dnaInput.matches("[ATCG]+$")) {
            dnaSequence=dnaInput;
            int [] count=new int[4];
            if (dnaSequence!=null) {
                for (int i=0; i<dnaSequence.length(); i++) {
                    switch(dnaSequence.charAt(i)) {
                        case 'A':
                            count[0]++;
                            break;
                        case 'T':
                            count[1]++;
                            break;
                        case 'C':
                            count[2]++;
                            break;
                        case 'G':
                            count[3]++;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Sorry You have invalid Type DNA sequence");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Now : A"+count[0]);
                System.out.println("Now : T"+count[1]);
                System.out.println("Now : C"+count[2]);
                System.out.println("Now : G"+count[3]);

                /*
                Pattern  p=Pattern.compile("A");
                Matcher m=p.matcher(dnaSequence);
                int j=0;
                while(m.find())
                j++;
                System.out.println(j);
                */
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("THE SEQUENCE SHOULD BE CONTAIN ATCG");
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say my input AAATATTTTGGGCC , Now how i can compressed this to A3TAT4G3C2 , what is the process i should follow 
And also how Ii can decompress it again. like how i can get this AAATATTTTGGGCC again

Comment: You can drop the null check: `dnaSequence` will never be null.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Note that your code as-shown doesn't perform either process you've described.

Comment: You might like to do some research into "Run length encoding"...

Comment: If you ask a specific question, we'll be happy to answer. However, this site is not meant for quick solutions to homework problems. Your question seems like a broad outline of a homework assignment followed by skeleton code that does nothing.

Comment: Here's a hint: loop over each character in the string and keep track of its value.  Then you're only interested in counting occurrences of _matching_ characters.  Once you encounter a new character (that doesn't match), stop counting, update the output, and start looking for matches again.

Comment: Hey madprogramer , thanks I got it yaaaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

You implement decompress your own.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompressDecompress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a Sequence of DNA: ");
        String dnaInput=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter E for encrypt or Enter D for decrypt");
        String function=in.nextLine();
        if("E".equalsIgnoreCase(function)){
            System.out.println(compress(dnaInput) );
        }else if("D".equalsIgnoreCase(function)){
            System.out.println(deCompress(dnaInput) );
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }

    private static String compress(String toCompress){
        StringBuilder compressedSB = new StringBuilder();

        char tempChar=' ';
        for (int i=0,counter=1;i<toCompress.length();i++){
            if(tempChar!=toCompress.charAt(i)){
                tempChar=toCompress.charAt(i);
                compressedSB.append(tempChar);
                if(counter>1){
                    compressedSB.append(counter);
                    counter=1;
                }
            }else{
                counter++;
            }
            if (i==toCompress.length()-1){
                compressedSB.append(counter);
            }
        }
        return compressedSB.toString();
    }

    private static String deCompress(String toDeCompress){
        return null;    
    }
}
```

And of course add the validation using regex or CASE for 'ATCG'

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my implementation if you want to do it without using string regex:

```
public String compress(String str) {
 String mystr = "";
 char last = str.charAt(8);
 int count = 1;
 for (int i = 1; i < str.lengthQ; i++) {
 if (str.charAt(i) == last) { // Found repeat char
 count++;
 } else { // Insert char count, and update last char
 mystr += last + "" + count;
 last = str.charAt(i);
 count = 1;
}
 }

return mystr + last + count;
}
```

FYI I too implemented only compress feature.